# What does TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_with_AES_128_CCM means collectively. What is the signature algorithm and keys used here?

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, keys, ciphersuite

Will the signature algorithm be ECDSA and key (i) ECC key or (ii) ECDHE and ECDSA keys?

Answer (score 3):

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_with_AES_128_CCM

- **ECDHE**: Key exchange with Ephemeral Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman
- **ECDSA**: Signature with Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm
- **AES_128** : 128-bit Encryption with Advanced Encryption Standard
- **CCM**: Mode of Operation with Counter with CBC-MAC which is an authenticated encryption algorithm designed to provide both authentication and confidentiality.

ECDHKE_ECDSA key exchange is performed as defined as in [rfc4492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492) and the x-coordinate of the shared secret is applied to a KDF to derive the key. The same key both in AES and CCM.

CCM combines CTR mode of operation and [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC). It has an authenticate-then-encrypt authenticated encryption.  Firstly, the message tag $t$ is calculated on the message by CBC-MAC then the message and the tag are then encrypted using [counter mode (CTR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)). In the above, the encryption is done by AES. CCM only defined for 128-bit block sizes.

- The good

  - this scheme can work on a single key.
  - The encryption scheme is semantically secure under a chosen-plaintext attack.
  - The MAC function is unforgeable under a chosen message attack.
- The bad:

  - Like any mode uses CTR internally (e.g. GCM) the (key,IV) pair reuse must not occur.

It is defined in [rfc7251](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7251) with 4 ECC

```
CipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM = {0xC0,0xAC}
CipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM = {0xC0,0xAD}
CipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 = {0xC0,0xAE}
CipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8 = {0xC0,0xAF}
```

And it is mentioned that these cipher suites make use of the AEAD capability in TLS 1.2 [RFC5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) in June 2014

The `8` means use eight-octet authentication tags and the default is `16` octets

Comment: Note: until TLS 1.3, the TLS doesn't mandate a KDF.